# Mandrill API - Handlebar each loop in Table

Tags: php, html, handlebars.js, mailchimp, mandrill

I use the Mandrill API to send my transactional Mails via PHP.

Now I'm running in the problem, that when I try to loop through multiple vars only the last one is shown.

this is my variable for `global_merge_vars`

```
array(
        array(
            'name' => 'products',
            'content' => array(
                array(
                    "name" => "Product 1",
                    "price" => "65€"
                ),
                array(
                    "name" => "Product 2",
                    "price" => "65€"
                ),
                array(
                    "name" => "Product 3",
                    "price" => "65€"
                )
            )               
        )
    );
```

My issue is glued to the products part with the array as content.

So if i try the following:

```
{{#each products}}
  {{name}} - {{price}}<br>
{{/each}}
```

I get

```
Product 1 - 65€
Product 2 - 65€
Product 3 - 65€
```

So far so good...

but if I try to wrap the whole thing in a table, I always just get the last array element shown...

```
<table>
  {{#each products}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{name}} - {{price}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

results in:

```
Product 3 - 65€
```

Actually, I think, it's just a stupid mistake on my side, but right now, I have no idea what is the problem!

So thank you all in advance for your help :)

___________________UPDATE________________________

i also found out, that it works if i put the whole table in the loop, like the following:

```
{{#each products}}
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>{{name}} - {{price}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
{{/each}}
```

but thats not really what i want as stated before :)

Comment: Could you try {{this.name}} instead of {{name}} inside the loop. Can't really figure out why your code didn't work.

Comment: thanks for your reply! unfortunately i had the same idea but it didn't make any difference :/

Comment: what if you add `tbody` ? `<table><tbody>
  {{#each products}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{name}} - {{price}}</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}</tbody>
</table>`

Comment: nope, unfortunately exactly the same as before :(

Comment: @FalcoB Which version of handlebars are you using?

Comment: @Vishnudev actually, i have no idea, because its inside of the mailchimp template creation form... so mailchimp takes care of handlebar

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue.. Displaying the content in a `<li>` works fine but as soon as I try a table it only shows the last item. I've tried everything I can think of with no luck.

Comment: @kjpc-tech check my answer if you still have a problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably too late for OP but after spending a few hours trying to understand this, I came across the solution on a GitHub thread.
Basically you put your handlebar tags on a HTML comment like this:

```
<table>
  <!-- {{#each products}} -->
  <tr>
    <td>{{name}} - {{price}}</td>
  </tr>
  <!-- {{/each}} -->
</table>
```

credits: [gurpreetatwal](https://github.com/handlebars-lang/handlebars.js/issues/604#issuecomment-429706439)

Comment: yea, unfortunately too late but seems to work! great! :)

Answer (score 0):

Have never used Handlebars before so forgive me if I'm completely missing something, but I was intrigued and tried to reproduce.

Handlebars version is: 4.0.12.

HTML:

```
<script id="header" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

    <table>
        {{#each content}}
             <tr>
                <td>{{name}} - {{price}}</td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </table>
</script>
```

Js (I just run `json_encode()` on your array) :

```
<script>
var products = [
    {
        "name": "products",
        "content": [
            {"name": "Product 1", "price": "65"},
            {"name": "Product 2", "price": "65"},
            {"name": "Product 3", "price": "65"}
        ]
    }
];
var theTemplateScript = $("#header").html();
var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);

$(document.body).append(theTemplate(products));

</script>
```

And got the expected output of:

```
Product 1 - 65
Product 2 - 65
Product 3 - 65
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! but unfortunately that does not resolve my issue because actually you did the same like me, just noch from mandrill/mailchimp